# Can't push my code to Heroku: Permission denied <public key> fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to push my code to Heroku with this line:

```
git push heroku master
```

But I keep getting the following error/message:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,50.85.49.333' <RSA> to the list of known hosts. 
Permission denied <public key>
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I have uploaded my key:

```
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

And set my remote to the git url:

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:project-name.git
```

And still no luck. Could anyone point out the problem?

I am following [THIS](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/8/25/java) short tut.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku 'Permission denied (publickey) fatal: Could not read from remote repository' woes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626944/heroku-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-reposito)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really should have searched harder before posting this question as I found the answer in another question with an almost identical name.

[Heroku 'Permission denied (publickey) fatal: Could not read from remote repository' woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626944/heroku-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-reposito)