# Heroku push updates app, but not remote git branch

Tags: git, heroku

I'm using Heroku for my project.

Lately, when I tried to push updates to the project, I noticed it shows me an enormous number of objected counted (over 15K files), which is not the case (changed around 3K).

I tried to open the project on SourceTree and noticed that the local branch and the remote branch of "master" have a great difference between them. **However, I am 100% sure that I pushed the presumably unpushed commits, and I am also sure the files are present in the Heroku app.**

I think Git thinks the remote branch is on an old commit, therefore making the files count too large when it really shouldn't be. I think something is wrong with the tracking.

I tried to call "git fetch" but nothing refreshed. It seems like some of my previous "git push" calls **updated the app, but not the remote branch.**

Is there any solution to that? Maybe an online visual of the remote Heroku branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I am 100% sure that I pushed the presumably unpushed commits, and I am also sure the files are present in the Heroku app.

If you don't have any current local changes, you could simply reset your local master branch to hekoku/master

```
git reset --hard heroku/master
```

I would recommend doing a backup of your current repo first.
Or simply [re-clone the heroku repository](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app)  and go from that new local clone.

---

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184899/user3184899) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698914/heroku-push-updates-app-but-not-remote-git-branch/60700968?noredirect=1#comment107412685_60700968):

> It seems like:
>
> - cloning it again,
> - [plus adding a new SSH key to my Mac's list of known keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17631730/6309)
> - and then trying to push it, solved it for now.

Comment: It seems like cloning it again, plus adding a new SSH key to my Mac's list of known keys (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17631730/3184899), and then trying to push it, solved it for now. Hopefully, it will keep working like that. Thanks!

Comment: @user3184899 Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.