# Deployment Ruby Rails with GIT on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am working on Ch.1 Ruby on Rails tutorial (Rails 5) with cloud IDE
I have the problem with deploying with Heroku.

The last command:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

produces an error message:

```
remote: ! No such app as murmuring-atoll-61945.
fatal: repository ‘https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-atoll-61945.git/’ not found
```

When I visit the address and run `heroku create`
it did not deploy hello_app.

Comment: what is the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: This solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447081/heroku-push-app-problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have renamed your application. You might want to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447081/heroku-push-app-problem).